# jQuery mobile local storage and PHP

Tags: jquery, mobile, storage, local

I'm attempting to use local storage to allow the user of my JQM web app control of the theme. I can't figure out how to get the local storage data back to php so it can generate the correct theme though.

At the moment, I have a form which allows the user to select the colours they would like. When the form is submitted, I store the selected values in a session variable which I use in my PHP code to generate the pages.
I also store the values in local storage on the user's browser.

The problem comes when the user closes their browser and re-visits the site.
I need to read the preferences from local storage, which I can do using JavaScript. Then I need to store those values in my session variable so my php code can read it. I've tried the following which shows me an alert box with 'success' but doesn't seem to actually be calling the PHP code:

```
var themeDefault = (window.localStorage && window.localStorage.getItem('theme') != "" && window.localStorage.getItem('theme') != null) ? window.localStorage.getItem('theme') : "a";

$(document).live('pageinit', function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "theme.php",
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: {"theme=" + themeDefault},
          success: function(){
                alert('success');
          }
  });
});
```

Is there anything wrong with the above code? Why won't it call theme.php even though I get the 'success' message?

The other problem is, I only want to execute this code once one the landing page only. How can I get it to do that? Currently, it executes once on every page.

My other option is going with cookies. Do you think that would be a better plan?

Comment: yes consider using cookie as an option cookies is a way to store data on user pc's you may use php to create the cookie with the preferred theme as a value and an expiry date for 1 year as example when the user submit the form ... and than in the login page you can read the cookie value and do the rest

Comment: Thanks Sora, I've taken your advice and got it working using cookies. I'd love to know how to do this using local storage though!

Comment: what do you mean by local storage ? you mean like storing the preferred theme of your client into your server ?